# C# saving and retrieving data in textfile... When option is selected, data is doubled

Tags: c#, save

So I'm doing a school assignment where a user is prompted with 3 options. 
-Register - Where a user registers and an instance of his properties is saved in a list, and then saved in a textfile.

-Login - User enters username and password, and upon having them validated, the user is logged in for another menu. The menu has an option where the user can buy a coffee. Upon buying the coffee, a coffee point is awarded. Keep in mind that users have a property called coffee points, which increments by 1 every time he buys a coffee. 
I'm not gonna describe the other options as they are not important.

-Exit- just exits.

So the code for getting the current textfile data is:

```
public static List<string> textLines = new List<string>();

textLines = File.ReadAllLines("Customer.txt").ToList();
    foreach (string userData in textLines)
    {
        //Extract a new Customer object from each userData
        Customer c = new Customer();
        string[] customerData = userData.Split('^');
        c.iName = customerData[0];
        c.iSurname = customerData[1];
        c.iID = customerData[2];
        c.iEmail = customerData[3];
        c.iHomeAddress = customerData[4];
        c.iMobile = Convert.ToInt32(customerData[5]);
        c.iUsername = customerData[6];
        c.iPassword = customerData[7];
        c.iCoffeePoints = Convert.ToInt32(customerData[8]);

        //Add customer object to customer list
        customerList.Add(c);

     }
```

The code for the registration is:

```
public static void RegisterCust() //Asking the customer for his/her 
registration information
{
    Customer c = new Customer();
    Console.Write("\nName: ");
    c.iName = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Surname: ");
    c.iSurname = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("ID: ");
    c.iID = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Email Address: ");
    c.iEmail = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Home Address: ");
    c.iHomeAddress = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Mobile Number: ");
    c.iMobile = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("Username: ");
    c.iUsername = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Password: ");
    c.iPassword = Console.ReadLine();

    c.iCoffeePoints = 0;

    //Checking if the customer username already exists in the textfile
    bool usernameCheck = (from custUser in customerList
                         where custUser.iUsername == c.iUsername
                         select custUser).Any();

    //Checking if the customer email already exists in the textfile
    bool emailCheck = (from custUser in customerList
                      where custUser.iEmail == c.iEmail
                      select custUser).Any();

    //Checking if the customer ID already exists in the textfile
    bool idCheck = (from custUser in customerList
                   where custUser.iID == c.iID
                   select custUser).Any();

    bool bariUsernameCheck = (from bariUser in baristaList
                   where bariUser.iUsername == c.iUsername
                   select bariUser).Any();

    bool bariEmailCheck = (from bariUser in baristaList
                   where bariUser.iEmail == c.iEmail
                   select bariUser).Any();

    bool bariIDCheck = (from bariUser in baristaList
                   where bariUser.iID == c.iID
                   select bariUser).Any();

    /*If bool userNameCheck = true, 
        bool emailCheck = true
        bool idCheck = true, 
        meaning there already is that username, email or ID in the 
        textfile, then print the error message and call RegisterCust()*/
    if (usernameCheck || bariUsernameCheck) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Username already in use. Please input the data again.");
        RegisterCust();
    }
    else if (emailCheck || bariEmailCheck)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Email already in use. Please input the data again.");
        RegisterCust();
    }
    else if (idCheck || bariIDCheck)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ID already in use. Please input the data again.");
        RegisterCust();
    }
    else //else, if every property is unique, then add the customer into the customerList
    {
        customerList.Add(c);
        Console.WriteLine("\nRegistered!");
        Console.WriteLine();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); //Program waits for 1 second
        Console.Clear();
        CustomerSaveToTxt();
        Main(null);
        }
    }
```

The login code is:

```
public static void customerLogin()
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nUsername");
    cu2.iUsername = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Password");
    cu2.iPassword = Console.ReadLine();

    bool usernameLoginCheck = (from custUser in customerList
                              where custUser.iUsername == cu2.iUsername
                              select custUser).Any();

    bool passwordLoginCheck = (from custUser in customerList
                              where custUser.iPassword == cu2.iPassword
                              select custUser).Any();

    bool userOrBari = (from custUser in customerList
                              where custUser.iPassword == cu2.iPassword && custUser.iUsername == cu2.iUsername
                              select custUser).Any();

    bool bariUsernameCheck = (from custUser in baristaList
                             where custUser.iUsername == cu2.iUsername
                             select custUser).Any();

    bool bariPasswordCheck = (from custUser in baristaList
                             where custUser.iPassword == cu2.iPassword
                             select custUser).Any();

    bool userOrBari2 = (from custUser in baristaList
                       where custUser.iPassword == cu2.iPassword && custUser.iUsername == cu2.iUsername
                       select custUser).Any();


    if (usernameLoginCheck && passwordLoginCheck && userOrBari)
    {
        menuUser();
    }
    else if (bariUsernameCheck && bariPasswordCheck && userOrBari2)
    {

        baristaLoggedIn();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong username or password. Input them again please.");
        customerLogin();
    }

}
```

Code for saving items in list into the textfile:

```
public static void CustomerSaveToTxt() //this method saves all the data inputted in the customer textfile
{
    foreach (Customer Customer in customerList)
    {
        customerOutput.Add(Customer.iName + "^" + Customer.iSurname + "^" + Customer.iID + "^" + Customer.iEmail + "^" + Customer.iHomeAddress + "^" + Customer.iMobile + "^" + Customer.iUsername + "^" + Customer.iPassword +"^"+Customer.iCoffeePoints);
     }
        File.WriteAllLines("customer.txt", customerOutput);

}
```

Code for buying coffee and incrementing the coffee point:

```
Coffee method = new Coffee();
    //Call the method "PerparingCoffee();"
    method.PreparingCoffee();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Coffee done! 1 point added to your coffee points!");

    //First I get the customer from customerList with a username = to the username entered to login.
    var cp = from custUser in customerList
                  where custUser.iUsername == cu2.iUsername
                 select custUser;

   string nName = "";
   string nSurname = "";
   string nID = "";
   string nEmail = "";
   string nHomeAddress = "";
   int nMobile = 0;
   string nUsername = "";
   string nPassword = "";
   int nCoffeePoints = 0;
   //I used the variables above to store the user's properties inside them, however coffee points increments by 1
   foreach (Customer s in cp)
   {
       nName = s.iName;
       nSurname = s.iSurname;
       nID = s.iID;
       nEmail = s.iEmail;
       nHomeAddress = s.iHomeAddress;
       nMobile = s.iMobile;
       nUsername = s.iUsername;
       nPassword = s.iPassword;
       nCoffeePoints = s.iCoffeePoints + 1;
   }

   //I created a new instance with the variables holding the information
   Customer c6 = new Customer();
   c6.iName = nName;
   c6.iSurname = nSurname;
   c6.iID = nID;
   c6.iEmail = nEmail;
   c6.iHomeAddress = nHomeAddress;
   c6.iMobile = nMobile;
   c6.iUsername = nUsername;
   c6.iPassword = nPassword;
   c6.iCoffeePoints = nCoffeePoints;


   customerList.RemoveAll(x => x.iUsername == cu2.iUsername && x.iCoffeePoints == nCoffeePoints - 1);
   customerList.Add(c6);
   CustomerSaveToTxt();
```

Now, when I run the program and register, the user is saved correctly in the textfile. Furthermore, while not closing the console application, when I press login and buy a coffee, it duplicates the textfile's content. Meaning that if, before I registered, I had 4 users saved in the textfile: Users A, B, C, D, upon registering and going directly to login and buying a coffee, my textfile would look like this: A, B, C, D, A, B, C, D, E, where E is the new user. However, if I run the program, register, then close the console application, run it again, log in and buy a coffee, it would work perfectly. Meaning that my textfile would look like: A, B, C, D, E. It's a really annoying problem which I don't know how to fix. Help would be REALLY appreciated!

Thanks!

***EDIT:I fixed the problem by first clearing the customerList right before I got the customers from the textfile, and the I cleared the customerOutput list in the customerToTxt method. Thanks all that helped!!

Comment: There is a bunch of code there. Can you post just the relevant part? I doubt many will read your whole code.

Comment: Everything connects to each other.. I didn't want to post all that code but everything is like a chain.

Comment: As Cid said - far too much code. Is there any possibility you are reading the customer text file a second time - I cannot see where you delete the customer list before you start adding the file contents. Possibly - because you seem to recursively call Main from the RegisterCust method - in fact you really ought to look at using a loop rather than recursion in that method.

Comment: Perhaps the problem lays in how you handle your customer list, every time you are calling the method CustomerSaveToTxt() you are re iterating with all the customer list previously saved in the txt file. I would suggest in order to debug it, that you deliberately remove a client before performing the bug and seeing if the output changes

Edit: I didnt meant saved in the txt file becase the WriteAllLines re makes it, but you are adding it to the customerOutput

Comment: Thanks for the replies. In the registration part, right before I add the instance to customerList, I tried clearing the list (customerList.Clear();), and then get the data from the textfile and then add the customer instance to customerList, and finally call the method customerSaveToTxt(). However it did not work.. I'm pretty lost and don't know what to do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not clearing the list before using it. So rewrite this part of the code like this

```
 public static void CustomerSaveToTxt() //this method saves all the data inputted in the customer textfile
  { 
        customerOutput.clear();
        foreach (Customer Customer in customerList){
            customerOutput.Add(Customer.iName + "^" + Customer.iSurname + "^" + Customer.iID + "^" + Customer.iEmail + "^" + Customer.iHomeAddress + "^" + Customer.iMobile + "^" + Customer.iUsername + "^" + Customer.iPassword +"^"+Customer.iCoffeePoints);
       }
   File.WriteAllLines("customer.txt", customerOutput); 
 }
```

Comment: Not that lol.. I fixed it.. I cleared the customerOutput just like u said, and I also cleared customerList right before getting the text data